# In my checkboxes if i have a 0 value it select this checkbox

Tags: forms

I have in my form a type 'checkboxes' form.

```
    // Form for the severity checkboxes.
    $kkkk_severity_levels = variable_get('kkkk_severity_levels', array());

    // Declare empty options array.
    $kkkk_severity_options = array();

    // Loop through each severity level and push to options array for form.
    foreach (watchdog_severity_levels() as $number_select => $severity) {
      $kkkk_severity_options[$number_select] = drupal_ucfirst(
        $severity);
    }

    // Checkboxes form.
    $form['kkkk_severity_levels'] = array(
      '#type'          => 'checkboxes',
      '#title'         => t('Type of log messages'),
      '#options'       => $kkkk_severity_options,
      '#default_value' => array_values($kkkk_severity_levels),
      '#required'      => TRUE,
    );
```

In these lines of code the watchdog_emergency has a key 0 so when i select something from checkboxes i take selected also emergency always as it gets me out : e.g if i select 'info' with key 6 it gets me out:

```
6 (String, 1 characters ) 6
0 (Integer) 0
1 (Integer) 0
2 (Integer) 0
3 (Integer) 0
4 (Integer) 0
5 (Integer) 0
```

7 (Integer) 0
and so it selects also the 'emergency' with key as 0... How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how the form API handles multiple selections for form elements.

You can easily solve it with standard language features:

```
$selected = array_filter($form_state['values']['kkkk_security_levels']);
```

Comment: where i will do that line of code?

Comment: In the submit handler.

Comment: i did it but it also selects the emergency :'(

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. `array_filter()` will remove all elements that have a value of zero, which every element in the array you put in your question has. I suspect your issue is somewhere else